# Plotly: How to format text (underline, bold, italic)

Tags: python, text, formatting, plotly, underline

I try to underline text in plotly when using annotations.
I add my annotations using

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
g = go.FigureWidget(make_subplots(rows=1,cols=1))
g.update_layout(annotations=[dict(text='my text')]) #plus any other parameters
```

Is there an option (in the annotations dict, maybe?) to have underlined text?

Thanks!

Comment: Here’s a frame shift that doesn’t solve your problem but may make it go away: underlined text is unusual in traditional typgraphy: try finding underlined text in an actual, professionally typeset book or newspaper. You’ll be hard-pressed to find examples (and in web typography it’s usually reserve for hyperlinks). So consider whether you actually want to use underlining to style your text. It doesn’t look professional.

Comment: It was meant to be the header of a figure legend, where I think it fits. In general, I would agree with your consideration

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plotly uses a subset of HTML tags to format text like bold `'<b></b>'` and italics `'<i></i>'`. Alas, `'<u></u>'` does not seem to be included at the moment. But linebreak *is* included, so you could make a little work-around like this:

```
string = "These are orange"
myText = string+'<br>'+ '-'*len(string)
```

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23])])

string = "These are orange"
myText = string+'<br>'+ '-'*len(string)

fig.update_layout(annotations=[dict(x='orangutans',y = 15, text=myText, font=dict(family='Courier New, monospace'))])
fig.show()
```

**Plotly source:** using `help(fig.layout)`:

```
  text
 |                  Sets the text associated with this annotation.
 |                  Plotly uses a subset of HTML tags to do things
 |                  like newline (<br>), bold (<b></b>), italics
 |                  (<i></i>), hyperlinks (<a href='...'></a>).
 |                  Tags <em>, <sup>, <sub> <span> are also
 |                  supported.
```

Comment: definitely a nice partial workaround,  not really suitable for my application, but I consider accepting it as a "solution" if there are no better ones appearing

Comment: @MaxS Thanks for the feedback! I tried a few other approaches as well with some dismal results. I'll include them if you're interested. Maybe you'll be able to find the necessary tweaks.

Comment: Like mentioned above at at comment to the question, I wanted to use it as a header for a legend and the solution was not fitting because the space for the newline is too much, maybe this could be changed as well, but then you start implementing workarounds for workarounds...

Comment: +1 for the `text` documentation, thanks!  (Was trying to use `<ul>` for bullet lists. Nope.) Minor correction (for v4.1.1 anyways) the `text` docs are under `help(graph_objects.layout.Annotation)`.

Answer (score 4):

Came here to find an answer, and found a better one from the reply.
Since "span" is supported. you can do

```
string = "These are orange"
myText = "<span style='text-decoration:underline;'>"+string+"</span>"
```