# How to format plotly title in python as bold when the title is a variable?

Tags: python, plotly

I know how to format the title as bold if the title is entered as a string using html tags:

`layout = go.Layout(title='<b>Bold</b>')`

but how do I get it to work if the title is assigned to a variable?

```
title = 'Bold'
layout = go.Layout(title='<b>'title'</b>')
```

Comment: Put some `+` in between, or use format strings: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly: How to format text (underline, bold, italic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093880/plotly-how-to-format-text-underline-bold-italic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sake of completeness, I am adding @SyntaxVoid comment as the working solution/answer. This works:

```
title = 'Bold'
layout = go.Layout(title='<b>'+title+'</b>')
```